# error it showing Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: yii

```
$sensor = Yii::app()->zdb->createCommand("select * from tbl_sensor where stype=2 and nid=$nid order by timestamp desc limit 10")->queryAll(); 

if($sensor)

 { return $sensor->sdata/10; } 

else 

{ return null; }
```

Comment: this will provide multiple row. you can not access like that. $sensor is array of objects

Comment: than what should i do , plz ?

Comment: explain your problem more. what you want ? multiple data or single data?

Comment: i want multiple date , because i use in graph

Comment: but i show in integer , but my requirement is  , what i got , i divide it with 10 , like sdata/10

Answer (score 0):

QueryAll is return array. use Like this

```
foreach($sensor as $key => $row) { 
     $yourvar = $row['sdata'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

QueryAll will give you array of arrays of data..

**To get all the columns:**

```
$sensor = Yii::app()->zdb->createCommand("select * from tbl_sensor where stype=2 and nid=$nid  order by timestamp desc limit 10")->queryAll(); 
if($sensor) { 
    foreach($sensor as $data_row) {
        foreach($data_row as $data_key => $data_value) { 
             echo "$data_key: $data_value\n";
        }
    }
} 
else { 
    return null; 
}
```

**To get just sdata:**

```
$sdata_values = Yii::app()->zdb->createCommand("select sdata from tbl_sensor where stype=2 and nid=$nid  order by timestamp desc limit 10")->queryColumn(); 
if($sdata_values) { 
    foreach($sdata_values as $sdata_value) {
        echo $sdata_value / 10;
    }
} 
else { 
    return null; 
}
```